# Girth in Graph.

Tags: graph-theory

A simple graph of girth 5 in which every vertex has degree at least
$k$ has at least $k^{2}+1$  vertices, with equality achieveable when $k$ $\epsilon$ $\left \{ 2,3 \right\}$.

Not getting how to solve !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick your starting vertex, *v*.

*v* has at least *k* neighbors (none of which are adjacent, because otherwise we have a cycle of length 3), call them $v_1, ... v_k$.

Each of the *k* neighbors $v_i$ has at least $k-1$ neighbors besides $v$ itself.  Call them $u_{i,1}, u_{i,k-1}$.  The $u_{i,j}$ are distinct from all of the $v_i$, because otherwise we would have a cycle of length 3.  Furthermore, all of the $u_{i,j}$ are distinct from each other, because otherwise we would have a cycle of length 4.

Count up the distinct vertices so far:  There is 1 vertex $v$.  There are $k$ vertices $v_i$.  There are $k(k-1)$ vertices $u_{i,j}$.

$1 + k + k(k-1) = 1+k + k^2 -k = 1 + k^2$.

Equality is achievable when $k=2$ (just take a 5-cycle) or $k=3$ ([the Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph))